# Group rows by dense_rank() and loop through each sub-group and compare another column in next row of that sub group?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, window-functions

I have tried the following in LINQPad:

```
create table users
(
    id int not null,
    startdate datetime not null,
    enddate datetime not null
)

go

insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(1, '01/01/2000', '01/02/2000')
insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(1, '01/03/2000', '01/04/2000')

insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(2, '01/01/2000', '01/02/2000')
insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(2, '01/03/2000', '01/04/2000')
insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(2, '01/05/2000', '01/06/2000')

insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(3, '01/01/2000', '01/02/2000')
insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(3, '01/03/2000', '01/04/2000')
insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(3, '01/06/2000', '01/07/2000')

insert into users(id, startdate, enddate) values(4, '01/01/2000', '01/02/2000')

go

select * from users 

go

// This query gave the result seen in the image

select id, startdate, enddate, rownum = dense_rank() over(partition by id order by enddate) from users
```

[image]

I want to write a query which will return only the IDs 1 and 2 (not 3 and 4) because:

- ID 1 - has more than 1 rows and startdate of its rownum 2 is 1 day
  ahead of enddate of its rownum 1
- ID 2 - has more than 1 rows and
  startdate of its rownum n + 1 is 1 day ahead of enddate of its rownum
  n
- ID 3 - THOUGH has more than 1 rows, startdate of its rownum 3 is
  NOT 1 day ahead (but 2 days) of enddate of its rownum 2. Hence, it is
  not qualified
- ID 4 - DOES NOT HAVE more than 1 rows. Hence, it is not
  qualified

Could you let me know how to get this result please?

Comment: So what is the resullt that you expect: just the list of `id`s that satisfy the conditions (that would be two records, with values `1` and `2`), or all the records whose `id`s satisfy the conditions?

Comment: Just the list of IDs i.e., two records - 1 & 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use window function `lag()` to recover the previous `enddate`, then aggregation and filter in the `having` clause:

```
select id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(enddate) over(partition by id order by enddate) lag_enddate
    from users t
) t
group by id 
having 
    count(*) > 1
    and max(case 
        when lag_enddate is null or startdate = dateadd(day, 1, lag_enddate) 
        then 0 else 1 
    end) = 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb079ef7eba1043fedcab2510beb1632)**:

```
| id |
| -: |
|  1 |
|  2 |
```

---

In archaic versions of SQL Server, that do not support window functions, you can emulate `lag()` with a correlated subquery:

```
select id
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        (select max(enddate) from users t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.enddate < t.enddate) lag_enddate
    from users t
) t
group by id 
having 
    count(*) > 1
    and max(case when lag_enddate is null or startdate = dateadd(day, 1, lag_enddate) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88dbba537d45d3993d368ce204fa6e84)**

Comment: Thank you. Could you send me the < SQL Server 2012 version as well please? LAG   is not recognized in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @MAK: I updated my answer with a solution without `LAG()`